# What is the purpose of __name__?

Tags: python

What does `__name__` do? I have only seen it paired with `__main__` and nothing else.

I know that the classic `if __name__ == __main__:` defines the behavior when acting as a package vs running as stand-alone.

However what other usages are there for `__name__`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does if \_\_name\_\_ == "\_\_main\_\_" do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do).  I realize that you mentioned your knowledge of that particular use, but the accepted answer does give you the answer you seek.

Comment: `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)`

Comment: I don't see the answer that I want.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`__name__` is `"__main__"` if you're executing the script directly. If you're importing a module, `__name__` is the name of the module.

foo.py:

```
print(__name__)
```

bar.py

```
import foo
```

Run the scripts:

```
$ python foo.py
__main__
$ python bar.py 
foo
```

Comment: Is there any other usage other than knowing the module's name?

Comment: The "if __name__ = '__main__' idiom allows you to create different behaviors based on whether a script is called directly or as a module. That's the most common use case. It might potentially have some use in debugging or reporting in unit tests.